# QueryFailedError Postgres malformed array literal "checkin,checkout", AWS serverless

Tags: typescript, postgresql, amazon-web-services, nestjs, typeorm

Payload:

```
{"name":"test","actions":["checkin","checkout"],"statuses":["approved","invited","chargeback_settled","activated","payment_required","registered","free"]}
```

Attribute of entity:

```ts
 @JoiSchema(Joi.array().items(Joi.string()))
  @Column({ type: 'simple-array', array: true })
  actions?: string[];
```

This works in our integration tests:

```ts
  const obj: Project = await projectsService.create({
  name: 'MyProject',
  actions: ['action1', 'action2'],
  statuses: ['status1', 'status2'],
  tenant_id: tenant_id,
});
```

It also works in end to end tests.

If however POSTed via Frontend with aboves exact payload it produces this error in Cloudwatch:

```
QueryFailedError: malformed array literal: "checkin,checkout"
```

Any clue as to why?

Comment: Check your code where you're inserting the payload as is. Most likely, the actions field being passed is `"checkin, checkout"` instead of `["checkin", "checkout"]`.

Comment: @RahulSharma Well, matter of fact is, it was the exact payload I posted, I copied it from the network tab in developer tools. So the array was in fact NOT malformed.

However, even though irreproducable through end to end tests, I fixed it by using a different way to annotate via Column annotation which fixed it. I will post the fix as an answer to my own question.

It just bugs me that it wasn't reproducable in end to end tests nor integration tests nonetheless. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  @JoiSchema(Joi.array().items(Joi.string()))
  @Column('simple-array', { nullable: true })
  actions?: string[];
```

**Changing the column annotation** to this has fixed it, for anyone else having the problem.

**The issue however, is STILL NOT reproducable via end to end tests or god forbid even integration tests.**

**So this issue only arises from a call from an actual other application context, only god knows why. Anyhow, this fixes it.**